# How to make a variadic is_same?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

How can I make a class template that returns whether any of its variadic types are equal to the first type. I want to be able to do this:

```
is_same<T, A, B, C>::value; // true if T is one of A, B or C
```

And if `T` is equal to any one of those types, its static `value` member will be `true`, otherwise `false`. How can I do this?

Comment: Since your intent wasn't clear (two people made the same wrong interpretation) I took the liberty to slightly rephrase your question.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use template recursion:

```
template<typename T, typename... Rest>
struct is_any : std::false_type {};

template<typename T, typename First>
struct is_any<T, First> : std::is_same<T, First> {};

template<typename T, typename First, typename... Rest>
struct is_any<T, First, Rest...>
    : std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_same<T, First>::value || is_any<T, Rest...>::value>
{};

static_assert(is_any<int, char, double, int>::value, "error 1");   // OK
static_assert(is_any<int, char, double, short>::value, "error 2"); // error
```

Answer (score 46):

Nice and concise with C++17:

```
template <class T, class... Ts>
struct is_any : std::disjunction<std::is_same<T, Ts>...> {};
```

And the dual:

```
template <class T, class... Ts>
struct are_same : std::conjunction<std::is_same<T, Ts>...> {};
```

A variation that uses fold expressions:

```
template <class T, class... Ts>
struct is_any : std::bool_constant<(std::is_same_v<T, Ts> || ...)> {};

template <class T, class... Ts>
struct are_same : std::bool_constant<(std::is_same_v<T, Ts> && ...)> {};
```

Or as C++20 concepts:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
concept is_any = std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<T, Ts>...>;

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
concept are_same = std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<T, Ts>...>;
```

Comment: this is much cleaner than the checked answer, I feel it should get the checkmark instead, even though the question has a c++11 tag

Comment: The first variation works on C++14, and adding `disjunction` will make it compile even on C++11.

Comment: I like the disjunction/conjunction solution. Can it be written as a C++20 concept?

Answer (score 17):

In C++17 you have an even nicer solution, using template variables and fold expressions:

```
template<class T, class... Rest>
inline constexpr bool are_all_same = (std::is_same_v<T, Rest> && ...);
```

And the usage is also simpler than all other examples:

```
are_all_same<T, A, B, C>
```

No `::value`, no parentheses!

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it's not really *transitive* friendly. I can't make my own type trait thingy and then link it to `are_all_same` by simply inheriting from it. The same problem applies to alias templates. Therefore, I still prefer to use the approach posted by `mavam`.

Comment: True, but note that in C++20 you can turn this into a concept and then composition is trivial.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this.  First, a small metaprogramming library, because it adds like 2 lines to do it generically:

```
template<template<typename,typename>class checker, typename... Ts>
struct is_any_to_first : std::false_type {};

template<template<typename,typename>class checker, typename T0, typename T1, typename... Ts>
struct is_any_to_first<checker, T0, T1, Ts...> :
  std::integral_constant< bool, checker<T0, T1>::value || is_any_to_first<checker, T0, Ts...>::value>
{};
```

Then a 2 line implementation of `is_any_same_to_first`:

```
template<typename... Ts>
using is_any_same_to_first = is_any_to_first< std::is_same, Ts... >;
```

And for completeness, the original `is_all`, which may also prove useful:

```
template<template<typename,typename>class checker, typename... Ts>
struct is_all : std::true_type {};

template<template<typename,typename>class checker, typename T0, typename T1, typename... Ts>
struct is_all<checker, T0, T1, Ts...> :
  std::integral_constant< bool, checker<T0, T1>::value && is_all<checker, T0, Ts...>::value>
{};

template<typename... Ts>
using is_all_same = is_all< std::is_same, Ts... >;
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/YNeEro) of the `is_all_same`.

Note that calling `is_any_same_to_first` anything less explicit is asking for trouble.  2/3 people who tried to answer this question, including me, assumed that `is_same<A,B,C>` is true iff all three are the same type!

Comment: Hmm I see you made the other decision than me (`is_all_same` instead of `is_any`). Truth be told, I hesitated to ask OP for clarification about that.

Comment: Um...This code will only work if *all* the types are the same. I'm looking for if `T` is *either* `A`, `B`, or `C`.

Answer (score 3):

Using the relaxed C++14 constexpr functions, these kinds of things are much easier to code, and probably much faster to compile as well, so you could write:

```
template <class T, class ... Candidates>
constexpr bool is_all_same() {
    bool pairs[] = {std::is_same<T,Candidates>::value...};
    for(bool p: pairs) if(!p) return false;
    return true;
}

template <class T, class ... Candidates>
constexpr bool is_any_same() {
    bool pairs[] = {std::is_same<T,Candidates>::value...};
    for(bool p: pairs) if(p) return true;
    return false;
}
```

This is enabled by the fact that in C++14 constexpr functions can have for loops.

Comment: isn't is_same_v c++17? Maybe have to use is_same<>::value with c++14

Comment: @xwl You're right, `is_same<>{}` works in C++14 too, since `struct is_same<>` has an `operator bool` overload.

Answer (score 0):

The most **generic** version that works :

- since C++11
- without dependencies (no `#include <type_traits>` needed)
- only one name `is_same` works for n-types (no `is_same_all` needed)

```
template <typename First, typename Second, typename ... Next>
struct is_same {

    template <typename A, typename B>
    struct is_same_min {
        enum { value = false };
    };

    template <typename A>
    struct is_same_min<A,A> {
        enum { value = true };
    };

    template <typename X, typename Y>
    constexpr static bool check() {
        return is_same_min<X,Y>::value;
    };

    template <typename X, typename Y, typename Z, typename ... K>
    constexpr static bool check() {
        return is_same_min<X,Y>::value and check<Y, Z, K...>();
    };

    enum { value = check<First, Second, Next...>() };
};
```

Just use `is_same<T1,T2,T3...>::value`