# How can you statically check that a type T exists in a variadic template parameter list

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, static-assert, service-locator

I am trying to statically check to see if a type exists in a variadic template parameter list. However, this template list actually exists within a class that is passed a single type. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032310/how-to-make-a-variadic-is-same) shows how to check a list of parameters or a parameter pack, but I am unsure how to test a class that contains variadic templates.

For example

```
template <typename ...S>
class Services {};

template <typename Services>
class ServiceLocator
{
public:
      template <typename T>
      T& Resolve() 
      { 
           static_assert( check_t_exists_in_variadic_template_within_Services );
           return Find<T>();  
      }

};
```

What could I write in this static_assert to ensure that each call to this service locator is checked and a compiler error thrown if Resolve is called with a type that does not exist in the template parameter list inside Services?

What I am specicially after is something along the lines of:

```
static_assert(is_any<T,Services::S...>::value, "T does not exist in Services::S");
```

Comment: Yes I think it might be, thanks. I spent ages trying to find an example of this

Comment: Actually, it would still be nice to see how this is done in my context since I am still quite new to the variadic template syntax

Comment: @makar I don't quite see what we could put "in your context". My answer there already has a `static_assert` example, you only need to unpack your variadic `Services` arguments instead of providing a fixed list of types like I did.

Comment: Add the implementation of `is_any` and then do a `static_assert( is_any<T, Services...>::value, "my error message" );`

Comment: I have updated my question with something more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method using `constexpr`:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
constexpr bool contains() {
    return false;
}

template <typename T, typename A, typename... Tail>
constexpr bool contains() {
    return std::is_same<T, A>::value ? true : contains<T, Tail...>();
}

int main()
{
    // usage: contains<type_you_want_to_check, type_1, type_2,...>()
    static_assert(contains<float, int, double, float>(), "does contain float");
    static_assert(contains<float, int, double, char>(), "does not contain float");
}
```

Aside from being simpler and easier to understand (IMO), this method has the advantage of being easily extensible to other needs, as you can replace the `std::is_same` call with any other `constexpr bool` expression, such as `std::is_base_of` in order to check if the parameter pack contains any base or derived types.

Answer (score 2):

One issue with your current code is that ServiceLocator takes a concrete type so you lose the template parameters passed to Services. To retrieve them you need to typedef it somehow so I chose std::tuple since you can't typedef the variadic list directly.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Type, typename Collection>
struct contains;

template <typename Type>
struct contains<Type, std::tuple<>>
{
    typedef std::false_type result;
};

template <typename Type, typename ... Others>
struct contains<Type, std::tuple<Type, Others...>>
{
    typedef std::true_type result;
};

template <typename Type, typename First, typename ... Others>
struct contains<Type, std::tuple<First, Others...>>
{
    typedef typename contains<Type, std::tuple<Others...>>::result result;
};

template <typename ... S>
struct Services
{
    typedef std::tuple<S...> Collection;
};

template <typename ServicesType>
class ServiceLocator
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    T * Resolve()
    {
        static_assert(contains<T, typename ServicesType::Collection>::result::value, "Fail");
        return nullptr;
    }
};

class S1 {};
class S2 {};
class S3 {};

int main(int /*argc*/, char * /*argv*/[])
{
    Services< S1, S2 > services;
    ServiceLocator< decltype(services) > locator;

    locator.Resolve< S1 >();
    locator.Resolve< S2 >();
    locator.Resolve< S3 >(); // triggers static_assert

    return 0;
}
```

I only checked with clang but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [François' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19457842), here's a shorter version that avoids usage of `std::tuple` and uses `std::integral_constant` (via `true/false_type`) and provides a C++14-style `contains_v` alias. The general idea is the same though.

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct contains;

template <typename T>
struct contains<T> : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct contains<T, T, Args...> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T, typename A, typename... Args>
struct contains<T, A, Args...> : contains<T, Args...> {};

template <typename T, typename... Args>
constexpr bool contains_v = contains<T, Args...>::value;
```

You can use it like this:

```
static_assert(contains_v<float, float, double>,
    "failure: float not among <float, double>"); // does not trigger

static_assert(contains_v<int, float, double>,
    "failure: int not among <float, double>"); // triggers
```