# Limit allowed COM Interfaces by using template function with limited variadic parameters (std::is_same)

Tags: com, c++17, variadic-templates, sfinae, fold-expression

I have wrapper classes contaning COM pointers (or smart pointers) to different interfaces.

**INTEND:**
Some COM classes can be obtained from various other COM interfaces, and I want to make a template constructor with variadic types, which would allow passing  arguments only of appropriate types.

something like:

```
template <class T, class = typename 
   std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<IUnknown, T>::value>::type, class ... Types>
   class WithCOMptrbase
{
   protected:
   T* ptr_;

   public: 

   //construct smart pointer by copy
   WithCOMptrbase(T* ptr, bool AddRef = false)
     : ptr_(ptr)
   {
      if (AddRef) ptr_->AddRef();
   }

   /*construct a smart pointer by querying an interface from an argument of 
   a type which is the same as one of the variadics*/
   template <class TypeOther, class = typename
      std::enable_if<syd::is_same<Types... , TypeOther>::value... || 
      ...>::type> /*there needs to be a proper version*/
      WithCOMptrbase(TypeOther* ptr)
        : ptr_(cQueryInterface<T>(ptr))
      {}

//other methods
};
```

helper function:

```
template <class U, class = typename 
   std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<IUnknown, U>::value>::type>
   T* cQueryInterface<T>(U *ptr)
{
   T* out;
   HRESULT hr = ptr->QueryInterface(__uuidof(T), (void**)&out);
   if (!SUCCEEED(hr)) throw _com_error(hr);
   return out;
}
```

Therefore, I will define my wrapper class

```
class WrapperClass : protected WithCOMptrbase<IThis, IInterface1, IInterface2, IInterface3>
{
   //methods
};
```

So far I have found this thread: 
[How to make a variadic is_same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032310/how-to-make-a-variadic-is-same)
but it is only about structs, not functions.
My goal is to limit the possibility of passing inapproprtiate Interface pointer, hence not to deal with wrong interface errors at runtime.

**UPDATE:**
Since Composition is preferable over inheritance, I've done some rethinking and decided to use a template function rather than a template class. So far I've managed to combine given answers and came up with this:

```
template <bool S, class Out, class Other, typename
std::enable_if<S>::type* = nullptr>
//copy-construct Smart Pointer for same Interfaces
WComPtr<Out> WFilterSame(const WComPtr<Other>& pOther)
{
    return WComPtr<Out>(pOther);
}

template <bool S, class Out, class Other, typename
    std::enable_if<!S>::type* = nullptr>
//Query Interface if differ
WComPtr<Out> WFilterSame(const WComPtr<Other>& pOther)
{
    return pOther.QueryInterface<Out>();
}

template <class Out, class ... Permitted, class Other>
WComPtr<Out> WFilterComInterfPtr(const WComPtr<Other>& pOther)
{

    static_assert(std::is_same<Out, Other>::value ||
        (std::is_same<Permitted, Other>::value || ...),
        "Interface is not supported.");

    return WFilterSame<std::is_same<Out, Other>::value, Out>(pOther);
}
```

Now I can define a constructor of my COM wrapper class:

```
class WComClass
{
   private:
   WComPtr<Interface> pComPtr_; //My Smart COM pointer

   template <class Other>
   WComPtr<Interface> WFilter(const WComPtr<Other>& pOther)
   {
      return WFilterComInterfPtr<Interface, IAllowed1, IAllowed2>(pOther);
   }

   public:
   template <class Other>
   WComClass(const WComPtr<Other>& pOther)
      : pComPtr_(WFilter(pOther))
   {}

   //methods
};
```

So far it behaved as intended (WFilterComInterfPtr), I don't expect it to fail in the wrapper class costructor.

Comment: Unless you restrict what version of C++, we'll assume [tag:C++17] at this point.  Especially because it makes it easier to solve.  :)

Comment: Second, what goes wrong with your solution?  A syntax error in `WithCOMptrbase`?

Comment: Do you want the stored TypeOther to support *all* of the interfaces, or *one* of the interfaces?  One seems strange.  Ah, you want only poitners of `T` or` Types...` to be permited, and then you want to always store it as a `T`?  Sort of like a variant but no way to go back to the type stored.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I want to support All of the provided interfaces.

Comment: You could replace `class = typename 
   std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<IUnknown, T>::value>::type` by `static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<IUnknown, T>);`. If you don't have any fallback (and in the case of a primary template you don't), then this substitution failure will eventually lead to a hard error due to no alternative to pick

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik That is shockingly uninformative.  "I want to support All" doesn't tell me if the passed in type `TypeOther` must support each and every one of the interfaces, or you want to support if any of that list is passed in, or something else; this is because "support" is ambiguous.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, the Idea is to allow passing only the provided Interfaces, so in my case I would be able to construct WithCOMptrbase only when "IThis, IInterface1, IInterface2, IInterface3" types are passed as arguments. For now I successfully compile with those allowed tyes and get compile error for other (not allowed) interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with

```
   template <class TypeOther, class =
      std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<Types, TypeOther> || ...)>>        
      WithCOMptrbase(TypeOther* ptr)
        : ptr_(cQueryInterface<T>(ptr))
      {}
```

I mean... you're using three ellipsis instead of one (remove the ellipsis after `::value` and the one after `Types`) and you need an additional couple of parentheses.

Off topic: are you sure that works

```
template <class T, class ... Types, class = typename 
   std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<IUnknown, T>::value>::type>
   class WithCOMptrbase
```

?

SFINAE through a default type **after** a variadic list?

Comment: `(std::is_same_v<Types, TypeOther> || ...)`

Comment: Replacing `class =  std::enable_if_t<(syd::is_same_v<Types... , TypeOther> || ...)>` with `std::enable_if_t<(syd::is_same_v<Types... , TypeOther> || ...), bool> =true` permits multiple ctor overloads.  Also you have too many `...`, try `std::enable_if_t<(syd::is_same_v<Types, TypeOther> || ...), bool> =true`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki - Ops... not seen the one after `Types`; thanks.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - thanks; yes: not seen the ellipsis after `Types`; nice trick the one of the `bool` type; but not useful in this case (with only a constructor), if I understand correctly.

Comment: @max66 Works fine, though I have some problems with me wrapper class, but I guess it is another story. And yes, variadics need to be placed at the end. Thank you.

Comment: @max66 Imagine they add a 2nd constructor which takes one template `T*` and a SFINAE "test" clause.  With this design they conflict with annoying error messages; with the `, bool> = true` design they don't  I'm just suggesting a better default SFINAE "cargo cult" trick to always use to avoid a potential issue that may or may not apply in any given case.

Comment: @max66 I don't know what have changed, but since there are "<Types," instead of "<Types... ," I started to get E0289 "No instance of constructor matches the argument list". If I get back to just "Types", there is no such an error, though I have a new one, which is:
Error C2440 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'WithCOMptrbase<IModelDoc2,IPartDoc,IAssemblyDoc,IDrawingDoc>'. It worked and now it's broken(

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - I see the point (usually I use `std::enable_if_t< some test> * = nullptr` (because I'm lazy and use the default value for second template parameter of `std::enable_if`)) but I had never thought of use this technique as default; also when there is only one constructor. But, in effect... today I write a single constructor and I don't think to add another one... the next year I write another constructor... with my system I have a clash... Yes: I think is a good idea.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik - Sorry but I can't imagine what's wrong now; I can just say that `std::is_same<Types..., TypeOther>` is wrong (if `1 != sizeof...(Types)`, obviously). You should try preparing a full (and minimal) example. But I suppose isn't easy.

Comment: @max66, currently I have a working code which is:  template <class TypeOther = typename
  std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<Types..., TypeOther> || ...)>>
  WithCOMptrbase(WComPtr<TypeOther> ptr)
  : ptr_(ptr.QueryInterface<T>())
 {}

Comment: @max66 Last I checked, `void*` wasn't a valid type of a non-type template parameter, but I could imagine that had changed.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik - do you mean that is working `std::is_same_v<Types..., TypeOther>`? But what is `Types...`? Anyway... you're defining `TypeOther` using `TypeOther`. And the compiler doesn't complain?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - D'Oh! I didn't know at all that `void *` isn't a valid type for a non-type template parameter. And I've used it zillion of times! You have convinced me: `std::enable_if_t<some test, bool> = true`. Thanks.

Comment: @max I know it wasn't once, it may be now.

Comment: @max66, yes, it works, in contrast to not having Types expanded. Types... are the additional types to be accepted as a constructor arguments, and we compare TypeOther with each from expansion. I don't have a desktop with the internet connection now, so I ll try to update my question later when come home.

Answer (score 1):

How about CRTP to avoid some template:

```
template <typename Base, typename T>
class Impl
{
public:
    Impl() = default;
    explicit Impl(T*) { static_cast<Base*>(this)->ptr_ = cQueryInterface<T>(ptr); }
};

template <class T, class ... Ts>
class WithCOMptrbase : private Impl<WithCOMptrbase<T, Ts...>, Ts>...
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<IUnknown, T>::value);
    static_assert((std::is_base_of<IUnknown, Ts>::value && ...));

    template <typename, typename> friend struct Impl; // We don't have variadic friend :/
protected:
    T* ptr_ = nullptr;


public:
    using Impl<WithCOMptrbase, Ts>::Impl...;

    //construct smart pointer by copy
    explicit WithCOMptrbase(T* ptr, bool AddRef = false) : ptr_(ptr)
    {
        if (AddRef) ptr_->AddRef();
    }

    //other methods
};
```

Comment: Did I correctly understand: In your case you will generate all the possible overloaded constructors, unlike generating them "on demand" as in template in another answer?

Comment: Yes, that's the goal.

Comment: I get Error C3203: "unspecialized class template cannot be used as a template argument for template parameter". I also get "syntax error: '...' " for the line with  ' static_assert((std::is_base_of<IUnknown, Ts>::value && ...));'

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik: I fixed some typos.