# C++17: Generic (multiple-inheritance based?) check for template in parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, metaprogramming

I need some code to check whether a certain template is part of a parameter pack. To implement the check for normal classes, I use the multiple-inheritance based approach outlined e.g. by [Louis Dionne here](http://ldionne.com/2015/11/29/efficient-parameter-pack-indexing/) or [Agustín Bergé here](http://talesofcpp.fusionfenix.com/post-22/true-story-efficient-packing).

## Testing for a Class

The idea is that you wrap every class `T` in the pack in an `PackEntry` class, and then have `PackIndex` inherit from all `PackEntry` classes. This way, if you are looking for a class `A`, all you need to do is check if a `PackIndex` can be converted to the correct `PackEntry`. Throwing everything together, it looks like this:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>

template <class T>
struct PackEntry
{
    using type = T;
};

template <class... Ts>
struct PackIndex : PackEntry<Ts>...
{};

template <class T, class... Ts>
struct PackSearcher
{
    static constexpr std::false_type check(...);

    // This overload is used if the PackIndex below 
    // derives from PackEntry<T>, the overload above 
    // otherwise. 
    static constexpr std::true_type check(PackEntry<T>);

    using type =
        decltype(check(PackIndex<Ts...>{}));

    static constexpr bool
    value()
    {
        return type{};
    }
};

template <class... Ts>
struct Pack
{
    template<class T>
    static constexpr bool has() {
        return PackSearcher<T, Ts...>::value();
    }
};

int main() {
    static_assert(Pack<int, void>::has<int>());
    static_assert(! Pack<int, void>::has<bool>());
}
```

## Testing for a Specific Template

Now, this is all neat, but say that I have a template `Tmpl`, and I want to know whether my pack contains *any* specialization of that template. I's easy to do if the template has a specific form, say `template <std::size_t> class Tmpl {};` Basically, the only difference is that inside the `PackSearcher` (which I now call `TmplPackSearcher`, you make the compiler derive the correct `N` template parameter for the template.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>

template <class T>
struct PackEntry
{
    using type = T;
};

template <class... Ts>
struct PackIndex : PackEntry<Ts>...
{
};

template <template <std::size_t> class T, class... Ts>
struct TmplPackSearcher
{ 
    static constexpr std::false_type check(...);

    template <std::size_t N>
    static constexpr std::true_type check(PackEntry<T<N>>);

    using type =
        decltype(check(PackIndex<Ts...>{}));

    static constexpr bool
    value()
    {
        return type{};
    }
};

template <class... Ts>
struct Pack
{
    template<template <std::size_t> class T>
    static constexpr bool has_tmpl() {
        return TmplPackSearcher<T, Ts...>::value();
    }
};

template<std::size_t I>
class Tmpl {};

int main() {
    static_assert(Pack<Tmpl<1>, int>::has_tmpl<Tmpl>());
    static_assert(!Pack<int>::has_tmpl<Tmpl>());
}
```

## The Question

Now, my question is: How do I test for the presence of a template in a parameter pack *without making any assumption how the template looks like*? I.e., I don't want to write separate code for `template<std::size_t>`, `template<std::size_t, typename>`, `template <typename, typename>`, etc.

Bonus points if it can be done using the same multiple-inheritance trick.

Comment: I don't think you can match a template of unknown signature against anything (except concrete instantiations of course). You can have template template parameters but only for known template signatures. You similarly can't match a function template against anything (except, again, something that deduces the instantiation to use). But I'd be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: It looks like this is impossible.

Comment: In other words, the issue here is first and foremost the lack of an "interface" for passing arbitrary templates (or function templates) to such a "tester". If each template to be tested was wrapped in a type (and had a fixed name in that type - compare `operator()` for functors) then things would look differently, because then you could pass these templates around (and not just their instantiations). But as it stands you've arrived at one of the limitations of the C++ templating system.

Comment: not sure if I understood the question correctly, but is what you're asking the same thing as the `is_any` template function answer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032310/how-to-make-a-variadic-is-same)?

Comment: Note that this approach fails if you have multiple options, e.g. `static_assert(Pack<Tmpl<1>, int, Tmpl<2>>::has_tmpl<Tmpl>());`

Comment: @xception: No, that `is_any` only works for classes, not templates, right?

Comment: works for classes as well as templated classes, but not templates with a undefined type if that's what you're looking for...

Comment: @Barry: It should be pretty easy to repair it by declaring each function template in an indirect base class instantiated with the class template detected via partial specialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @MaxLanghof mentioned in comments, it's not even possible to declare a `has_tmpl` that accept arbitrary kinds of templates. It's possible to have overloads of `has_tmpl` with different template parameters (`template<std::size_t> class`, `template<std::size_t, typename> class`, `template <typename, typename> class`, etc), but an infinite number of overloads are needed.

Instead, let's use a type that wraps the template, and expose everything we need. The simplest way AFAIK is (ab)using a lambda: `[]<std::size_t I>(type_identity<Tmpl<I>>){}`.

And then the problem is almost trivial: `has_tmpl` can be simply defined to return `(std::is_invocable_v<Lambda,type_identity<Ts>> || ...)`.

Complete example:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class> struct type_identity {};

template <class... Ts>
struct Pack
{
    template<class Lambda>
    static constexpr bool has_tmpl(Lambda) {
        return (std::is_invocable_v<Lambda, type_identity<Ts>> || ...);
    }
};

template<std::size_t I>
class Tmpl {};

int main() {
    static_assert(Pack<Tmpl<1>, int>::has_tmpl([]<std::size_t I>(type_identity<Tmpl<I>>){}));
    static_assert(!Pack<int>::has_tmpl([]<std::size_t I>(type_identity<Tmpl<I>>){}));
}
```

Note that this uses a GNU extension that is standardized in C++20 (template-parameter-list for generic lambdas). I don't think this is avoidable.

It should be possible to use multiple inheritance, but fold expression is much shorter ;)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for (I implemented the `Pack` class, without testing your inheritance "trick").

```
#include <type_traits>

// just for testing
template <typename... Ts> struct Foo {};
template <typename... Ts> struct Bar {};

// compare templates
template <template <typename...> typename, typename>
struct is_same : std::false_type {};

template <template <typename...> typename T, typename... Ts>
struct is_same<T, T<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};

// find templates in list
template <template <typename...> typename T, typename... Pack>
struct searcher
    : std::integral_constant<bool, std::disjunction_v<is_same<T, Pack>...>> {};

// your class (only template params changed)
template <class... Ts>
struct Pack {
  template <template <typename...> class T>
  static constexpr bool has_tmpl() {
    return searcher<T, Ts...>::value;
  }
};

int main() {
  static_assert(Pack<int, long, Foo<int>>::has_tmpl<Foo>());
  static_assert(Pack<int, long, Foo<int, short>>::has_tmpl<Foo>());
  static_assert(Pack<int, long, Foo<int, short, long>>::has_tmpl<Foo>());

  static_assert(!Pack<int, long, long>::has_tmpl<Foo>());
  static_assert(!Pack<int, long, Bar<int>>::has_tmpl<Foo>());
  static_assert(!Pack<int, long, Bar<int, short>>::has_tmpl<Foo>());
  static_assert(!Pack<int, long, Bar<int, short, long>>::has_tmpl<Foo>());
}
```

Comment: OP wants to be able to check against `template<int> struct Baz{};`.

Comment: ah I see. you could easily make this work with non-type template params, but it won't work with types and non-types mixed. not flexible enough, my bad.