# trait is_same for arbitrary many types

Tags: c++, type-traits

The [type_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) library offers the possibility to check if two type are the same with [`is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same).

How can one generalize to an arbitrary long list of types? Something declared as

```
template <class... U>
struct is_same_many;
```

with a field `value` such that `value = true` if all `U`s are the same, and `false` otherwise.

Comment: See [How to make a variadic is_same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032310/how-to-make-a-variadic-is-same).

Comment: With C++17 you can use fold expressions: `template <typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr bool is_same_v = (std::is_same_v<T, Ts> && ...);`

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/f11djvon7

Comment: @joergbrech Make that an answer.

Comment: @lorro It is already an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52328061/12002570)

Comment: Yes, better mark this a duplicate